# Copying html files to create erb versions with bash script

Tags: regex, macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to write a bash (OSX) script that finds all html files in a directory and copies them to create erb files with underscores at the beginning of the file name. So `test1.html` would become `_test1.html.erb` for instance.

I was trying to do it a bit like this but there's probably a better way (and this way isn't finished)

`find . -regex '.*/[^_].*\.html$' | while read file; do [need to do the copy X.html file to create new _X.html.erb file in here]; done`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `for` loop version:

```
for file in *html ; do
  cp ${file} _${file}.ebr
done
```

and here is a `find` version:

```
find ./ -name "*html" -exec sh -c 'cp {} _$(basename {}).ebr' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find *.html | while read files
do
newname="_${files}.erb"
mv -v "${files}" "${newname}"
done
```

Comment: I needed to copy the files but other than that it works perfectly, if you want to edit it and I'll accept the answer. Thanks!